# What gives an object its gravitational energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

To apply some force we need to spend some energy, like to move an object distance $\mathbf s$ with a force $ \mathbf F$ we must spend $ \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf s $ energy.

Now, every object has a gravitation force. Like our earth, It constantly pulling the object towards itself with it's the gravitational force, does this mean the earth is constantly losing energy, and if yes where this energy is coming from?

Comment: If you see the definition of potential energy, it is the energy possessed by virtue of its position in space. The fact that the two masses exist as such gives rise to the field and hence the energy.

Comment: The potential energy belongs to the system of objects, not to any one object.

Answer (score 1):

No the energy is already there in the system (in case of asteroids, planets,etc.) or is provided by you or some external agency (like evaporation of water via rays from sun, lifting a ball from the ground,etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The conservation of energy is one laws in physics. It says, that in a *closed system* energy is neither generated nor destroyed. Let's consider two examples

1. We take a ball $1m$ above the ground and let it go. What happens? The falls towards the earth center (=center of gravity). Thereby, it accelerates and transforms it *potential energy*  into *kinetic energy*. Once, the ball hits the ground the kinetic energy gets transformed into heat, which is another form of energy.
2. Let's consider the solar system. The earth and the sun are attracting each another due to their gravitational force. Thus, they fall towards each another -- although the sun is moving as well, let's assume that is remains at it's fixed position. This facilitates my writing. While the earth falls towards the sun it looses potential energy and gains kinetic energy -- analog to the falling ball. In contrast to the ball example, the earth does not collapse with the sun, but misses it. Thus, in the next step the earth transformed all the gained kinetic energy energy into potential energy: Have a look at the velocity of rotating object in [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit)

Comment: You don't even need a closed system. Changes in total energy of the closed system are merely energy fluxes (work on the system). Energy is neither created nor destroyed on a physical universal scale, by symmetry, as far as we can tell presently.

Comment: @BillN but there still is no good answer as to how two objects are so-called attracted. And the same goes for relativity, there is no good answer as to how mass can bend space.

Answer (score 0):

From a classical Newtonian/Galilean perspective:

> To apply some force we need to spend some energy, like to move an object distance s with a force F we must spend F⋅s energy.

Not really. An object at rest on a table has at least two forces acting on it: 1) the gravitational pull downward from the earth. 2) the net electromagnetic push away from the table (what we call the *normal* and *friction* forces). The forces are there, but no "spending" of energy.

> Now, every object has a gravitation force.

No. Any massive object,$m_A$, (Newtonian view) has a gravitational *field*,
$g_A$. If another massive object, $m_B$, interacts with that field, $m_A$ exerts a gravitational force on $m_B$ of $m_B g_A.$ Because the designations  $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, we could show that Newton's Third Law holds. But we *must* have an interaction of two objects (gravitational field of one with mass of the other, from an elementary perspective) in order to have this force. Forces in inertial reference frames *always* involve interactions of two objects.

> ... does this mean the earth is constantly losing energy

No, it means that if an object has a component of motion parallel to the direction of the force of gravity, the potential energy of the system will change, but so will the kinetic energy. If the gravitational force is the only force acting within the system of two objects, and nothing acts from outside, the sum of gravitational potential and kinetic will remain constant.

One could establish a reference frame in which an object is at rest and the earth moves toward or away from the object. In that case, the individual potential energies at different arrangements of the masses would be identical, and the change in PE would be identical to earth at rest and object moving toward (or away from) the earth. The kinetic energy of the earth, however, could be HUGE, at each position, but the change in KE would be the exact negative of the change in PE.

Classically, the potential energy is defined to be in the field-mass interaction.

From a modern perspective (general relativity, GR), masses cause space-time to bend, and masses move along the curvature of space-time caused the other masses. So there is no gravitational force in GR. That thought/concept can be disconcerting at first.